# M2: Issue with custom field

Tags: magento2

I install for test this small extension with custom field:
https://github.com/jainmegha5395/Add-Custom-Field-in-Magento-2-Registration-Form

In this extension register form require SKYPE ID. I disable this module, but still when I try register new account I get issue: Skype field is required field. But this field is not visible in register form. Any solution?

https://prnt.sc/s1olfu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below few steps

```
php bin/magento module:disable Custom_Field
sudo rm -rf var/* generated/* pub/static/frontend/*
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo php bin/magento ca:cl
sudo php bin/magento ca:fl
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/(project name)/
```

After those issue of the above command not resolved then remove the skype attribute and hit again above command.

```
DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'skype';
```

I hope this will help you...!

Comment: DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'skype'; solved issue.

Comment: That's great...!